# Oracle SQL remove Sunday and consider only 6 working days

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried this SQL CASE to get number of days left for Over KPI(OKPI).

There are 2 main conditions which are confusing me,

1- Remove or don't consider Sunday as a working day.

2- Actual bkg_date is after 1 day. So for example if bkg_date = '08 Jul 2023' then bkg_date will be = '10 Jul 2023'

```
CASE
    WHEN SYSDATE - (x.bkg_date + 1) <= x.dlvry_kpi THEN
        CASE
            WHEN x.dlvry_kpi - (
                -- Full weeks from Monday of start week to Monday of current week
                (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1, 'IW')) * 6 / 7
                -- Add extra days in the current week excluding Sunday
                + CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 <= 6 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 ELSE 6 END
                -- Subtract days in the week before the start date excluding Sunday
                - CASE WHEN TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1) - TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1, 'IW') <= 6 THEN TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1) - TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1, 'IW') ELSE 6 END
            ) <= 0 THEN '00 days left'
            ELSE
                TO_CHAR(
                    x.dlvry_kpi - (
                        -- Full weeks from Monday of start week to Monday of current week
                        (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1, 'IW')) * 6 / 7
                        -- Add extra days in the current week excluding Sunday
                        + CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 <= 6 THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 1 ELSE 6 END
                        -- Subtract days in the week before the start date excluding Sunday
                        - CASE WHEN TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1) - TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1, 'IW') <= 6 THEN TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1) - TRUNC(x.bkg_date + 1, 'IW') ELSE 6 END
                    )
                ) || ' days left'
        END
    ELSE 'OKPI'
END AS AGING
```

So, this is what I've come up with and gives the result OKPI for following inputs;

x.bkg_date = '08 Jul 2023'

sysdate = '17 Jul 2023'

x.dlvry_kpi = 7

Comment: Are there any other dates that you should not consider as a working day, i.e. public holidays? If this is the case you need a calendar table

Comment: Yes there are other public holidays but for now I just want the sunday to be left out.

Comment: We've established you don't want to user a calendar table. Now I suggest, that you add more detail on correct inputs and outputs. So, edit the question and put in a table that has a couple of different dates that cover a few specific scenarios and tell us what the output should be. This is part of a "MVCE" https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the next business day (skipping Sundays) using:

```sql
bkg_date + CASE TRUNC(bkg_date) - TRUNC(bkg_date, 'IW') WHEN 5 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (bkg_date, dlvry_kpi) AS
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + 8 - LEVEL, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT bkg_date,
       next_bkg_date,
       dlvry_kpi,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS today,
       (TRUNC(next_bkg_date, 'IW') - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')) * 6 / 7 AS full_weeks,
       LEAST(TRUNC(next_bkg_date) - TRUNC(next_bkg_date, 'IW'), 5) AS days_at_end,
       LEAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), 5) AS day_at_start,
       -- Full weeks from Monday of current week to Monday of end week
       (TRUNC(next_bkg_date, 'IW') - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')) * 6 / 7
       -- Add extra days in the end week excluding Sunday
       + LEAST(TRUNC(next_bkg_date) - TRUNC(next_bkg_date, 'IW'), 5)
       -- Subtract days in the current week before the today excluding Sunday
       - LEAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), 5) AS days
FROM   (
  SELECT bkg_date,
         bkg_date + CASE TRUNC(bkg_date) - TRUNC(bkg_date, 'IW') WHEN 5 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END as next_bkg_date,
         dlvry_kpi
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Outputs:

| BKG_DATE | NEXT_BKG_DATE | DLVRY_KPI | TODAY | FULL_WEEKS | DAYS_AT_END | DAY_AT_START | DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 2023-07-25 00:00:00 (TUE) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 6 | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| 2023-07-23 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2023-07-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 6 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 2023-07-22 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2023-07-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 6 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 2023-07-21 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2023-07-22 00:00:00 (SAT) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 2023-07-20 00:00:00 (THU) | 2023-07-21 00:00:00 (FRI) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 4 | 0 | 4 |
| 2023-07-19 00:00:00 (WED) | 2023-07-20 00:00:00 (THU) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 2023-07-18 00:00:00 (TUE) | 2023-07-19 00:00:00 (WED) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 2023-07-18 00:00:00 (TUE) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-07-16 00:00:00 (SUN) | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-07-15 00:00:00 (SAT) | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-07-14 00:00:00 (FRI) | 2023-07-15 00:00:00 (SAT) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | -6 | 5 | 0 | -1 |
| 2023-07-13 00:00:00 (THU) | 2023-07-14 00:00:00 (FRI) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | -6 | 4 | 0 | -2 |
| 2023-07-12 00:00:00 (WED) | 2023-07-13 00:00:00 (THU) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | -6 | 3 | 0 | -3 |
| 2023-07-11 00:00:00 (TUE) | 2023-07-12 00:00:00 (WED) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | -6 | 2 | 0 | -4 |
| 2023-07-10 00:00:00 (MON) | 2023-07-11 00:00:00 (TUE) | 1 | 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | -6 | 1 | 0 | -5 |

And to get the number of days left then:

```sql
SELECT bkg_date,
       dlvry_kpi,
       days,
       CASE
       WHEN days < -dlvry_kpi
       THEN 'OKPI'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(dlvry_kpi + days, 'FM90') || ' days left'
       END AS aging
FROM   (
  SELECT bkg_date,
         dlvry_kpi,
         -- Full weeks from Monday of current week to Monday of end week
         (TRUNC(next_bkg_date, 'IW') - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')) * 6 / 7
         -- Add extra days in the end week excluding Sunday
         + LEAST(TRUNC(next_bkg_date) - TRUNC(next_bkg_date, 'IW'), 5)
         -- Subtract days in the current week before the today excluding Sunday
         - LEAST(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), 5) AS days
  FROM   (
    SELECT bkg_date,
           bkg_date + CASE TRUNC(bkg_date) - TRUNC(bkg_date, 'IW') WHEN 5 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END as next_bkg_date,
           dlvry_kpi
    FROM   table_name
  )
)
```

Which outputs:

| BKG_DATE | DLVRY_KPI | DAYS | AGING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-24 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | 7 | 8 days left |
| 2023-07-23 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 | 6 | 7 days left |
| 2023-07-22 00:00:00 (SAT) | 1 | 6 | 7 days left |
| 2023-07-21 00:00:00 (FRI) | 1 | 5 | 6 days left |
| 2023-07-20 00:00:00 (THU) | 1 | 4 | 5 days left |
| 2023-07-19 00:00:00 (WED) | 1 | 3 | 4 days left |
| 2023-07-18 00:00:00 (TUE) | 1 | 2 | 3 days left |
| 2023-07-17 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | 1 | 2 days left |
| 2023-07-16 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 | 0 | 1 days left |
| 2023-07-15 00:00:00 (SAT) | 1 | 0 | 1 days left |
| 2023-07-14 00:00:00 (FRI) | 1 | -1 | 0 days left |
| 2023-07-13 00:00:00 (THU) | 1 | -2 | OKPI |
| 2023-07-12 00:00:00 (WED) | 1 | -3 | OKPI |
| 2023-07-11 00:00:00 (TUE) | 1 | -4 | OKPI |
| 2023-07-10 00:00:00 (MON) | 1 | -5 | OKPI |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cDZqnLnp)